# using user default browser with htmlloader

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

so I wrote code in an air app that auths with google / youtube.  The code itself is working as expected.  The problem is that when I open the auth window using HTMLLoader, it uses the default browser of the machine (safari on mac, ie on win) rather than the default browser that the user uses.  So existing sessions that the user has on their default browser are useless.  I have added code to account for all scenarios, but I would like to think there is a way to use the users preferred browser and benefit from logged in sessions etc.

I found and tried the property navigateInSystemBrowser which didn't sound like it would help... and interestingly that made the browser stop working.  The links in the browser window no longer worked.

Anyone know if this is possible?  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: What is the difference between the default browser of the machine and the default browser that the user uses?  How would you expect any automated system to know the difference without user input?  Regardless; I believe Adobe AIR on desktops uses an embedded version of WebKit; which is different from the user's browser of choice and the system's default browser.  I would not expect it to have access to any cookie or session data of other browsers installed on the machine.

Comment: Well there clearly is a difference to AIR between the default OS browser and the default USER browser. And AIR definitely does use session data from other browsers. if I am on mac with an active session in Safari, AIR sees and uses the session.  If I am on mac and using Firefox, AIR does not see the session.. even though Firefox is set to be my default browser... it always uses Safari sessions.  Same scenario on Windows with Internet Explorer.